# Magento: Issue installing on localhost

Tags: mysql, magento, installation

I'm trying to install magento on localhost, I've done it dozens of time before with success, but this time i'm facing strange issue. These are the steps i've taken so far:

1. Have fresh installation of XAMPP,
2. fresh copy of magento installation
3. added sample content's media files into magento directory
4. created new database with sample content mysql file.

When i try to install, the first 3 steps go well (asking name, time zone, language select etc), then i enter DB details, the next step gives this error:

```
There has been an error processing your request
```

The url shown on the error page is this:

```
http://localhost/gfashion/index.php/install/wizard/installDb/
```

I checked the error log, and it prints this error:

```
::1 - - [29/May/2014:08:16:40 +0500] "GET /gfashion/errors/report.php?id=1501102562&skin=default HTTP/1.1" 503 1866 "http://localhost/gfashion/index.php/install/wizard/installDb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"
```

Here is the content of the file 150110256 from folder var/report:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:210:"Error in file: "D:\xampp1\htdocs\gfashion\app\code\core\Mage\Core\sql\core_setup\mysql4-upgrade-0.8.18-0.8.19.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'core_variable' already exists";i:1;s:976:"#0 D:\xampp1\htdocs\gfashion\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 D:\xampp1\htdocs\gfashion\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '0.8.18', '1.6.0.4')
#2 D:\xampp1\htdocs\gfashion\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('0.8.18', '1.6.0.4')
#3 D:\xampp1\htdocs\gfashion\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 D:\xampp1\htdocs\gfashion\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 D:\xampp1\htdocs\gfashion\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 D:\xampp1\htdocs\gfashion\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 D:\xampp1\htdocs\gfashion\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:45:"/gfashion/index.php/install/wizard/installDb/";s:11:"script_name";s:19:"/gfashion/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: go to var/report/ and paste the content of 1501102562 file

Comment: please post the content of the file 1501102562 which will be in the folder var/report

Comment: content of file 1501102562 added to the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various methods with no success, i reinstalled another fresh copy of Magento, and it worked fine. The problem apparently was with some files which didn't get unzipped right, due to reason unknown to me.

I hope this'll help if someone encounters the same or similar problem.